# DatetimeArray Error when trying to use pandas.DataFrame.pct_change function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I am trying to calculate the annual percentage change of a DataFrame from Excel with 135 rows × 3 columns, the colums are 'Date', 'User 1' and 'User 2', but I get an error from the Date because I use the to_datetime function with that column.

The error is the following:

TypeError: cannot perform __ truediv __ with this index type: DatetimeArray

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
DF_EMP = pd.read_excel("D:\Users\Python\Employment.xlsx")
pd.to_datetime(DF_EMP.Date)
DF = DF_EMP.pct_change(periods=11)
```

[Part of the DF in a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npEdH.png)

Comment: if replace `pd.to_datetime(DF_EMP.Date)` to `DF_EMP = DF_EMP.set_index('Date')`  it working?

Comment: @jezrael It worked! another question is, if I need to calculate for example, January 2010 with January 2011, should I put period=12 instead of period=11 right?

Comment: yop, if dates are consecutive, it means no missing month(s) it should working.